# PHP Get and change a random item in an object

Tags: php, object, random

I know how to do this in an array, but not sure how to do it with an object. My object looks like this...

```
stdClass Object
(
    [Full] => 10
    [GK] => 10
    [Def] => 10
    [Mid] => 10
    [Att] => 0
    [Youth] => 0
    [Coun] => 0
    [Diet] => 10
    [Fit] => 0
    [Promo] => 10
    [Y1] => 0
    [Y2] => 9
    [Y3] => 0
    [IntScout] => 0
    [U16] => 0
    [Physio] => 4
    [Ground] => 1
)
```

I need to do a loop, checking that the total of the values isn't greater than a certain value (50 in this case). If it is, I need to take one of them at random and reduce it by 1, until eventually the total is no higher than 50.

My failed attempt so far is :-

```
$RandomTrainer = mt_rand(0, (count($this->Trainers) -1));
if ($this->Trainers->$RandomTrainer] > 0) {
$this->Trainers->$RandomTrainer] -= 1;
```

Obviously that doesn't work because it's looking for '0' or some number in the object, which isn't there.

I've skipped the loop / total part because that's working at my end.

Solution : Not perfect, but it works.

```
$TrainerArray = get_object_vars($this->Trainers); // Cast into array.
if ($Total> 50) { // Calculated before the loop.
    $TrainerFound = 0;
    while ($TrainerFound == 0) {
        $RandomTrainer = mt_rand(0, count($TrainerArray)) - 1; // Get a random index in the array of trainers.
        reset ($TrainerArray); // Set the array to the beginning, not sure if this is needed.
        while ($RandomTrainer > 0) {
            next ($TrainerArray); // Keep advancing '$RandomTrainer' times.
            $RandomTrainer -= 1;
        }
        $propertyName = key($TrainerArray); // Get the key at this point in the array.
        $this->Trainers->$propertyName -= 1; // Reduce the value in the original object at this point by 1.
```

Probably too long-winded but after a few hours, I'm happy with it just working :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get vars as array

```
$vars = get_object_vars($some_std_class_object);
```

then:

```
while(Your_function_to_sum_values($some_std_class_object) > 50)
{
    $propertyName = array_rand($vars);

    if(some_std_class_object->$propertyName > 0){
        some_std_class_object->$propertyName -= 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: I see what you're getting at here, but it's not quite working. $propertyName here still just returns a number, so I still can't apply that to my object. I need to get the key of $propertyIndex I think, but not quite sure how. 'key' seems to require the current index, which I don't think we have selected.

Comment: Updated my original post with my solution. It's a bit messy but it works. Thanks for your suggestions, I used most of it. Not sure if I can flag it as the correct answer though since it doesn't actually work.

Comment: My fault... array_rand actually returns the propertyName, i updated my code, so you can test it and mark this answer as correct. :)